# In Java Reactor : doOnError() or doOnException()?

Tags: java, exception, project-reactor, reactor

If I understood correctly the difference between Errors and Exceptions, shouldn't these functions be named `doOnException()` or `Mono.exception(new Exception("..."))` etc. ?

Nothing functional here, just a shower thought.

Comment: actually, these methods signrature contains `Throwable`, so it does handle `Error` as well. I think it's just a name, indicating it handles an error to the execution, and not `Error` object

Comment: I support your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

The two are not one and the same. The concept of reactive streams / reactive prorgamming isn't tied to Java, and so terminology and conventions will sometimes differ (such as in this case.)

The `Error` throwable object in Java is a specific subclass of `Throwable` to denote serious errors that the VM could never be reasonably expected to recover from (`StackoverflowError`, `OutOfMemoryError`, etc.) These, of course, differ from an `Exception` (which is generally considered recoverable.) Side note however, is that reactor doesn't actually distinguish between these - it can cope with any throwable.

An `error` in a reactive streams context is *any* unexpected error/exception/throwable that occurs whilst processing the stream, which is by default a terminal event (but in most reactive frameworks, reactor included, can be recovered from in a variety of ways.)

Comment: this. the name actually refers more to the concept of the `onError` signal from the Reactive Streams specification rather than the concept of the Error class from Java.